# Cursor start to blinking all over my a tag after I click "tawk.to" chat plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat, tawk.to

I just  integrate the chat plugin Tawk.to into my angular app, However chat is working fine but there is a cursor blinking issue.

The cursor start to blink on all my 'a' tags on all over the  page after I click chat box icon.

I tried the following in index.html file on my angular app:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
    Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
  (function () {
     var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
     s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
     s1.async = true;
     s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/API_KEY/default';
     s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
     s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
     s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
   })();
 </script>
```